# How to create a class to download a file in Python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to write a class in Python to open a specific URL given and return the data of that URL...

```
class Openurl:

   def download(self, url):

     req = urllib2.Request( url )
     content = urllib2.urlopen( req )
     data = content.read()
     content.close()
     return data

url = 'www.somesite.com'
dl = openurl()
data = dl.download(url)
```

Could someone correct my approach? I know one might ask why not just directly open it, but I want to show a message while it is being downloaded. The class will only have one instance.

Comment: Why does the need to show a message imply that you need a class? The two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: what exactly is your problem. is this not working?

Comment: it gives me error and stops..

Comment: python is case sensitive. `Openurl` != `openurl`!

Comment: python don't give an error. it gives you a complete stacktrace, which we should see to help you out :)

Comment: That's just a typo..there is something wrong with the coding...

Comment: You have a case error in "dl = openurl()" it should be with big "O".

Comment: Found the issue..in actual code I missed proper url(http) address..thanks guys

Comment: you can also use urllib.urlretrieve().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems.

One that I'm sure is not in your original code is the failure to import `urllib2`.

The second problem is that `dl = openurl()` should be `dl = Openurl()`. This is because Python is case sensitive.

The third problem is that your URL needs `http://` before it. This gets rid of an `unknown url type` error. After that, you should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

It should be `dl = Openurl()`, python is case sensitive

Comment: I just found that, but when I fixed it, it gives an error about the URL type.